# Add and populate new fields in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, search

We have ElasticSearch index that stores large dataset. I need to add two new fields to ES index and backfill values for these fields from Redshift. My question is how can I achieve this? What is the best approach: change existed ES scheme by adding 2 new fields or create new index with all needed fields. I am new to ES, so any suggestions, ideas will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reindex. And because you need to reindex all I’d recommend reindexing in a new index.

If you are using aliases which is a good practice, just switch the alias to the new index and drop the old index.

Comment: Why I cannot add new field to the existed index using update API? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html

Comment: You can. It will just cost you much more in term of IO instead of reindexing from scratch.